# Aurelia TypeScript -Webpack skeleton npm install gives error

Tags: aurelia

I've cloned the repo https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation
from this repo I'm using **'skeleton-typescript-webpack'**

But when i run the `npm install` command it gives me following error

> npm ERR! node v4.4.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.19 does not
>   satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements! npm ERR!
>   peerinvalid Peer karma-webpack@1.7.0 wants webpack@^1.4.0 npm ERR!
>   peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.0 wants
>   webpack@^2.1.0-beta
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\My
>   Projects\AureliaTs\skeleton-navigation-master\skeleton-typescript-webpack\npm-debug.log

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of the issue already on the Aurelia's Issue list: [ERR! peerinvalid after running npm install #584](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/584)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a 3.x version of npm. Your node version is fine (we support Node LTS and Node Latest Release), but for some reason, `npm` before version 3 doesn't work.

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1 server:dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --profile --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1 server:dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=....

Comment: I just installed and ran the latest Webpack TypeScript skeleton release on Node 4.4.7 with NPM 3.10.5 successfully. You might want to try removing the node_modules folder in your project, running `npm cache clean` then `npm install` and then `npm start` again. NPM can be a PITA sometimes.